# How do we unit-test functions which use randomness?

Tags: unit-testing, random

I am interested in best-practice techniques, if any, for unit-testing functions which use randomness. To be clear, I am **not** concerned with testing the distribution of random number generators.

As a toy example, let's consider this function:

```
// Returns a random element from @array. @array may not be empty.
int GetRandomElement(int[] array);
```

Answers to [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness) suggest that we may inject a mock source of randomness, which makes sense. But I'm not sure exactly how I might use the mock. For example, let's assume that we have this interface:

```
// A mock-friendly source of randomness.
interface RandomnessSource {
  // Returns a random int between @min (inclusive) and @max (exclusive).
  int RandomInt(int min, int max);
}
```

...And change the signature of `GetRandomElement()` to this:

```
// Returns a random element from @array, chosen with @randomness_source.
// @array may not be empty.
int GetRandomElement(int[] array, RandomnessSource randomness_source);
```

All right, now a test could look like:

```
MockRandomnessSource mock = new MockRandomnessSource();
mock.ExpectCall(RandomnessSource::RandomInt(0, 5)).Return(2);
AssertEquals(GetRandomElement({0, 10, 20, 30, 40}, mock), 20);
```

...which could work fine, but only if the implementation looks like this:

```
// A fairly intuitive implementation.
int GetRandomElement(int[] array, RandomnessSource randomness_source) {
  // Pick a random number between [0..n), where @n is the @array's legnth.
  return array.Get(randomness_source.RandomInt(0, array.Length()));
}
```

...But nothing in the function specification prevents an implementation like this:

```
// Less intuitive, but still a conforming implementation.
int GetRandomElement(int[] array, RandomnessSource randomness_source) {
  // Pick a random number between [1..n+1), only to subtract 1 from it.
  return array.Get(randomness_source.RandomInt(1, array.Length() + 1) - 1);
}
```

One idea which leaps to mind is that we may further constrain the function's contract, like this:

```
// Returns a random element from @array, chosen with @randomness_source by
// by calling @RandomnessSource::RandomInt to pick a random index between
// 0 and the length of @array.
int GetRandomElement(int[] array, RandomnessSource randomness_source);
```

...But I can't quite get over the impression that this is placing too heavy a constraint on the function contract.

I also suspect that there might be better ways to define the interface `RandomnessSource` to make its callers more amenable to unit tests, but I'm not quite sure what/how.

...Which brings me to the question: What are the best-practice techniques (if any) for unit-testing functions which use randomness?

Comment: It turns out that "random" is difficult to define. So the question becomes "why do you need 'random'"? For example, to test GetRandomElement you definitely don't need a random source.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Could you elaborate? Could you give an example of unit-testing GetRandomElement()?

Comment: The testing version of a `RandomnessSource` should return values at the extremes of its range, and then something towards the middle. You can make an decision about how much test coverage you want. You could even use a deterministic but "random" looking sequence, e.g. incorporating something like the java.util.Random class (if you're using Java) with a fixed seed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't want to unit test "randomness". Unit tests are mainly meant to determine if an expected input will give you an expected output. Very defined and structured. You want your unit tests to be very predictable and behave in the same way every time you run your tests.

If you truly want to test it the question then becomes how exactly do you want to test it? What happens if between two tests the outcome is different? How do you define a successful test vs a failed test?

These questions are all more obvious in normal unit tests where the outcome is very clear and well defined beforehand.

Comment: To answer your questions: yes, I'd like unit tests to be deterministic. More specifically, I'd like to test functions whose outcomes normally depend on sources of randomness by replacing such sources with deterministic ones, much as I'd test functions whose outcomes normally depend on time intervals by replacing time sources with mock clocks. If an outcome is different between two tests, I'd like to re-write the test to eliminate non-determinism. Pass/fail distinctions should conform to whatever is specified the surrounding test harness (e.g., in JUnit, to return without throwing exceptions).

Comment: @JaeHeonLee So then write those tests. Not sure how this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I'm having difficulty envisioning a way of mocking out sources of randomness so that the unit test verifies the contract rather than the implementation details. That's to say, I'd like to write a test which need not be re-written even if the code for GetRandomElement() is switched out from the "fairly intuitive implementation" snippet to the "less intuitive, but still a conforming implementation" snippet in the original post.

Comment: @JaeHeonLee As I said. You don't want to unit test "randomness". `GetRandomElement` in your case could be unit tested to ensure it behaves correctly given an empty array. That is something where the input given should produce the same output every time. If you give it an actual array it has the potential to have different outputs every time. You don't really unit test that. You can't test randomness. That's the whole point of it being random.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that you are thinking through this issue with me. But I do have doubts about the argument from non-determinism. For example, in the "a test could look like" snippet in the original post, I've provided an example which is deterministic. The difficulty seems not so much about eliminating non-determinism, but about de-coupling the test from the implementation details of the function under test (as I've tried to explain in the "I'm having difficulty envisioning..." comment).

Comment: @JaeHeonLee If you have language specific questions you really should have tagged it under that language. I’m just trying to answer the high level question of testing randomness. Which at the core is what you are asking. If that is incorrect adding tags and making your question more clear I believe is required.